# Sens de « à part entière »

Tags: sens, locutions

[Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/a%20part%20entiere), [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/%C3%A0%20part%20enti%C3%A8re) et le [Littré (cf le 4e en-tête)](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/part_%5B2%5D/54375) indiquent que « *à part entière = participant de plein droit* ».

Toutefois, la première fois, j'ai déchiffré cette tournure en tant que *à part + entière* et m'étais imaginé (à tort) qu'elle veut dire « abstraction faite de/excepté/hormis + la totalité/le tout [de qqch] ».

Dans « *à part entière* », *entière* est-il adjectif ou nom masculin ?

Comment décomposer « *à part entière* » pour dériver et parvenir à son sens propre ?

---

**Supplément suite à la réponse de Mark Thorin :**

Maintenant que Mark Thorin a épatamment tranché ma question originale, pourquoi **à** dans « ***à*** part entière » ? Pourquoi pas **avec** soit **en** soit une autre préposition ?

Toutefois, je saisis que **dans** ne convient pas ici car **dans** désigne l'intérieur de qqch.

Comment: Dans une locution le choix de la préposition est arbitraire, il n'y a pas d'explications. Ça ne sert à rien de poser des question là-dessus, il n'y a qu'avec l'expérience qu'on les apprend.

Comment: @LePressentiment Merci de votre appréciation, j'ai déplacé mon commentaire comme vous le souhaitiez.

Comment: @cl-r: Je vous en prie. J'ai plussoyé votre affichage comme promis.

Answer (score 7):

"**Part**" est toujours féminin.

Le mot signifie non seulement **portion**, mais aussi **participation** : "Vous n'avez point encor *[sic, licence poétique]* de part à nos misères" (Corneille), "Le hasard et la force ont beaucoup de part au succès" (Fénelon).

"**à part entière**" se dénoue donc comme "dont la participation est entière, n'est pas restreinte pour un motif quelconque".

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. Plussoyé. SVP, pourriez-vous répondre à mon supplément dans mon OP, dans votre réponse (Et non pas en tant qu'un commentaire) ?

Answer (score 1):

- *avec une part entière*, il y faut une part physique ou représentant une réalité : la part représente un objet que l'on définit précisément, nominativement.
- *à part entière* : selon le principe des parts complètes, parts qui peuvent être symboliques, mathématiques, juridiques ou réelles.